# Could not find or load main class org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool with gradle-jooq-plugin-3.0.1, jooq-3.11.2

Tags: gradle, jooq

I have a project using `gradle-jooq-plugin-3.0.1`, `jooq-3.11.2` and Spring Boot 1. When I try to generate JOOQ-Files I get the following error message:

```
> Task :generateSampleJooqSchemaSource FAILED
Error: Could not find or load main class org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool
```

This is a minified build file:

```
plugins {
  id 'nu.studer.jooq' version '3.0.1'
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.14.RELEASE'
  id 'java'
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  jooqRuntime 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.177'
  compile 'org.jooq:jooq'
}

bootRepackage.enabled = false

jooq {
  version = '3.11.2'

  sample(sourceSets.main) {
    jdbc {
      driver = 'org.h2.Driver'
      url = 'jdbc:h2:~/test-gradle'
      user = 'sa'
      password = ''
    }
    generator {
      database {}
      target {
        packageName = 'org.jooq.example.gradle.db'
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Any ideas? According to [gradle-jooq-plugin/README.md](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin/blob/master/README.md) this should be working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The plugin seems to ignore the configured version (3.11.2) and uses the version from Spring Boot (3.9.6). `org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool` was introduced only with JOOQ-3.11.0.

As a workaround you can override Spring Boot's JOOQ version:

```
ext['jooq.version'] = '3.11.2'
```

I've reported an issue for it: [gradle-jooq-plugin/issues/81](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin/issues/81)